# Moving average in MYSQL without dates but grouped by another column

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I have a table in MYSQL(version 5.7.33) which looks like shown below:

| Date | SalesRep | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | Jack | 10 |
| 2021-04-02 | Jack | 8 |
| 2021-03-01 | Lisa | 10 |
| 2021-03-02 | Lisa | 14 |
| 2021-03-03 | Lisa | 21 |
| 2021-03-04 | Lisa | 7 |
| 2021-03-08 | Lisa | 10 |
| 2021-03-09 | Lisa | 20 |
| 2021-03-10 | Lisa | 15 |

I want the moving average of Sale column, but don't want that to be based on the dates since the dates have gap, instead I want it based on row numbers and grouped by SalesRep. So something like this:

| Date | SalesRep | Sale | MoveAvg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | Jack | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-04-02 | Jack | 8 | 9 |
| 2021-03-01 | Lisa | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-03-02 | Lisa | 14 | 12 |
| 2021-03-03 | Lisa | 21 | 15 |
| 2021-03-04 | Lisa | 7 | 13 |
| 2021-03-08 | Lisa | 10 | 12.4 |
| 2021-03-09 | Lisa | 20 | 13.6 |
| 2021-03-10 | Lisa | 15 | 13.8 |

So the moving average is for all the dates from start to finish for a particular sales rep and then it starts over for another sales rep and so on. Is this possible to do in MYSQL? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yep, possible, and fairly straightforward. Go on . Try something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use avg as a window function with a frame clause for this:

```
SELECT dt, salesrep, sale,
     AVG(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY salesrep ORDER BY dt
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
       AS moveavg
```

Without window functions, you simply join all previous rows for each salesrep:

```
select a.dt, a.salesrep, a.sale, avg(b.sale) as moveavg
from mysterytablename a
join mysterytablename b on b.salesrep=a.salesrep and b.dt <= a.dt
group by a.salesrep, a.dt
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it this way but I keep getting syntax error so decided to ask.         
  SELECT DT, salesrep, sale,
     AVG(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY salesrep ORDER BY DT
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
       AS moveavg
       FROM table;

Comment: The error has to do with the version of MySQL I am using, its 5.7.33, the function OVER is not supported in this version I guess.

Comment: yes, you need mysql 8.  note that oracle will not support version 5.7 for much longer and consider upgrading

Comment: added a 5.7 version

Comment: Thanks, yes we are considering updating to 8.0 soon.